# Angular Object length in something wrong showing 4 data and count is 5

Tags: angular, object, count, variable-length-array

Angular Object length in something wrong showing 4 data and count is 5 why this display 5 instead of 4 count i can't understand why below thing happening

```
this.productOptionForm.controls.productOption['controls'][0].controls.optionList.controls.length
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't help if there's no code shared. What you say is really indecipherable

Comment: @Benny i have update question and one more images added also code added.

Comment: this.temp = this.productOptionForm.controls.productOption['controls'][0].controls.optionList.controls.length;
this.countForColor = this.temp - 1;   i am try and working fine but this is right or wrong @Benny

Comment: I think initially it is 5, then you console.log length is 5, but then there is a function or some change that changed the original value, browser only updates the value of the object but doesn't update re-value lenght, you can debug by comment all function or any set data bellow and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome dev tools shows a blue little `i` and when you move your mouse over it it will say **Value below was evaluated just now.** It means that when you first logged it to the console it was of length 5, and then when you expanded it it contained 4 elements only.